# Client-side code/presentation separation in a content templatized server-side

Tags: php, javascript, template-engine

I came to a situation where a great principle of separation of code and presentation produces a problem in web-application development, where there exist two separate parts: client and server. I'm not sure how to adhere to this principle on both ends simultaneously without tricks.

Consider an example with a server-side template, generating a client-side web-page (`view`), which should be aware of server-side `model` parameters, so that they can be send back to server. For example, it could look something like that:

```
<!-- File: form.template -->
<form id="main" name="main">
<input type="button" id="do" class="buttons" value="Do" onclick="requestDoFor(%modelid%)"/>
</form>
```

Such a template is used on server with proper separation from code (for instance, in php, using an abstract template engine):

```
$templateEngine->create('form.template', array('modelid' => $value))->render();
```

The problem is that the template does not conform to code separation principle on client-side. The generated view should be actually free from any JavaScript, that is the `onclick` handler should go from the template:

```
<input type="submit" id="do" class="buttons" value="Do" />
```

to a separate JavaScript file:

```
$('#do').click(function(){requestDoFor(%modelid%);});
```

The question is how to pass model parameters to this part of the client, which is not the `view` (in fact, this is a client-side part of `controller`), and is not generated by server-side template engine? I could imagine a quick workaround in the template:

```
<input type="submit" id="do" class="buttons" value="Do" objectid="%modelid%" />
```

and something like that in JavaScript:

```
$('#do').click(function(event){requestDoFor($(event.target).attr('objectid'))});
```

But it does not look perfect. Is there a better way?

I know some people generate views entirely as JavaScript, which in turn generates DOM elements in browser, but this approach has its own drawbacks. What else can be suggested?

Comment: What are the drawbacks of generating views in JavaScript? Why can't JavaScript drive the view? I don't see anything wrong with it, besides, there are some interesting tools to help you with generating HTML contents such as handlebarsjs (look it up on Google).

Comment: @JP, thanks for the comment. Could you possibly elaborate (in comments or as an answer) on how to get a handlebars template and a data for it in a single request? I can suggest a JSON container with both of them, and some "loader" which runs data against template, but it looks like a hack, because of multilayered structure (JSON->HTMLtemplate->JavaScript->HTML). Also, handlebars templates should be precompiled for better perfomance, it requires a switch between debug and production in server-side code and further complications in the "loader" to detect precompiled templates. Or no?